# Count Unique count for columns in Table Visual in powerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have this visual in power bi dashboard

I want to display the sum of all the positive values in the Margin column on the Card and the negative values in the Margin Column on another Card. First Card is 9 and the second card is 4 and third card 8

I tried this

```
 Count_PosMargin = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Margin]), 'Table'[Margin]>=0)
 Count_NegMargin = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Margin]), 'Table'[Margin]<0)
 Count_Acct = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Acct]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the COUNT function, use the SUM function to sum the values:

```
Count_PosMargin = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Margin]), 'Table'[Margin]>=0)    
Count_NegMargin = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Margin]), 'Table'[Margin]<0)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. I am interested in the count

Comment: If you want to count, then you already have the right DAX code. Just make sure you create Measures and not calculated columns.

Comment: The code is not returning expected output